# Parameter value [2022-04-13T09:20:49Z] did not match expected type [java.time.OffsetDateTime (n/a)];

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, datetimeoffset

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter
> value [2022-04-13T09:20:49Z] did not match expected type
> [java.time.OffsetDateTime (n/a)]; nested exception is
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value
> [2022-04-13T09:20:49Z] did not match expected type
> [java.time.OffsetDateTime (n/a)]

I am passing the `offsetDateTime` format to query, like .. hey DB get me records which are greater than equals to this date.

when I write the same query in the workbench, the same date format is working fine. And also it works when I write an equals to a given date from code. but when I try to write greater than equals to a given date, it gives this error.

```
private void getGenericSpecificationEqual(Object key, GenericSpecification genericSpecification, Object value) {
            genericSpecification.add(new SearchCriteria(value.toString(), key, SearchOperation.EQUAL));
        
}
private void getGenericSpecificationGTE(Object key, GenericSpecification genericSpecification, Object value) {
        genericSpecification.add(new SearchCriteria(value.toString(), key, SearchOperation.GREATER_THAN_EQUAL));
    
}
private void getGenericSpecificationLTE(Object key, GenericSpecification genericSpecification, Object value) {
        genericSpecification.add(new SearchCriteria(value.toString(), key, SearchOperation.LESS_THAN_EQUAL));
    
}
```

And in return, I am getting this error.

Also, I have tried with this format `2022-04-13T14:50:49+05:30` and got the same error.

I am using Spring JPA in my java code for DB interactions.

I would really appreciate any kind of solution or suggestions you can provide for this issue.

Comment: Last time you posted this question, I suggested that Hibernate expects an `OffsetDateTime` and you gave it a `String`. Were you able to check whether this was the problem?

Comment: @OleV.V. : Hi. thanks for the reply. yes i tested the same as you suggested, but i am just wondering if thats the issue then why EQUALS is working fine and not Greater than equals. If you can guide me further with a bit more clarity on this.

Comment: It’s not something I know, but I would think …

Comment: {

  "startDate": "2022-04-13T14:50:49+05:30",
  "endDate": "2022-04-13T14:50:49+05:30"
}

if i provide one of the dates, then i have equals to - It works!
if both dates are given then the logic should be greater than equals startDate and less than equal EndDate. - Then it doesn't work!

Comment: @OleV.V. : yes please. kindly let me know if you get anything.

Comment: Any findings on this will be appreciated! i am just stuck not finding a way forward :|